# Does a pure ABC in C++ need to be virtual?

Tags: c++

Suppose a pure abstract base class might be inherited by multiple paths in a dreaded diamond of death.  Is there any good reason to use virtual inheritance, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Multiple inheritance is rare and diamond pattern even more so. Reasons to use virtual inheritance include (1) avoiding ambiguous base class (I've seen this mentioned for exception interfaces, something that I haven't seen in real code), (2) for forcing a member initialization in the most derived class (it was a C++03 trick for making a class final), (3) for doing Java style inheritance of an implementation of an interface (called "dominance" in the inheritance tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good reason to use virtual inheritance, because the compiler will enforce it. Consider this scenario:

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() = default;
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B : A {};

struct C : A {};

struct D : B, C {
   void f() override {}
};
```

Without virtual inheritance, the following code won't compile

```
D d;
A &a = d; // error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'
```

When you change `B` and `C` such that

```
struct B : virtual A {};

struct C : virtual A {};
```

everything will build just fine.

Comment: `A &a = (B &)d;`? :-O

Comment: That's a suitable solution, as its awkwardness matches the one of the example itself^^

Comment: This example seems artificial, but on reflection I do care about the case where I call `void g(A& a);` with a D instance